# How can I save user messages and history to room database

Tags: java, android-room, greendao

I am developing a chat app and I want to save user chat history and messages using room database. By this, when the users start the app they can see their previous history and messages.

Below my User.java model class where implemented user model properties.

```
 @Entity
 public class User implements IChatUser {
     @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
     private Integer id;

     @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
     String name;

     @Ignore
     Bitmap icon;

     public User() {
     }

     public User(int id, String name, Bitmap icon) {
         this.id = id;
         this.name = name;
         this.icon = icon;
     }

     @Override
     public String getId() {
         return this.id.toString();
     }

     @Override
     public String getName() {
         return this.name;
     }

     public void setId(Integer id) {
         this.id = id;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }

     @Override
     public Bitmap getIcon() {
         return this.icon;
     }


     @Override
     public void setIcon(Bitmap icon) {
         this.icon = icon;
     }
 }
```

UserDao.java

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    List<User> getUsers();

    @Insert
    void insert(User user);

    @Delete
    void delete(User user);

    @Update
    void update(User user);
}
```

UserRoomDatabase.java

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class UserRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public  abstract  UserDao userDao();
}
```

MessengerActivity.java

```
public class MessengerActivity extends Activity{

    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int RIGHT_BUBBLE_COLOR = R.color.colorPrimaryDark;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int LEFT_BUBBLE_COLOR = R.color.gray300;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int BACKGROUND_COLOR = R.color.blueGray400;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int SEND_BUTTON_COLOR = R.color.blueGray500;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int SEND_ICON = R.drawable.ic_action_send;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int OPTION_BUTTON_COLOR = R.color.teal500;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int RIGHT_MESSAGE_TEXT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int LEFT_MESSAGE_TEXT_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int USERNAME_TEXT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int SEND_TIME_TEXT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int DATA_SEPARATOR_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int MESSAGE_STATUS_TEXT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final String INPUT_TEXT_HINT = "New message..";
    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int MESSAGE_MARGIN = 5;

    private ChatView mChatView;
    private MessageList mMessageList;
    private ArrayList<User> mUsers;

    private int mReplyDelay = -1;
    Realm realm;

    private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_messenger);

        initUsers();

        mChatView = findViewById(R.id.chat_view);


        //Load saved messages
        loadMessages(realm);

        //Set UI parameters if you need
        mChatView.setRightBubbleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,RIGHT_BUBBLE_COLOR));
        mChatView.setLeftBubbleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, LEFT_BUBBLE_COLOR));
        mChatView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, BACKGROUND_COLOR));
        mChatView.setSendButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, SEND_BUTTON_COLOR));
        mChatView.setSendIcon(SEND_ICON);
        mChatView.setOptionIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_circle);
        mChatView.setOptionButtonColor(OPTION_BUTTON_COLOR);
        mChatView.setRightMessageTextColor(RIGHT_MESSAGE_TEXT_COLOR);
        mChatView.setLeftMessageTextColor(LEFT_MESSAGE_TEXT_COLOR);
        mChatView.setUsernameTextColor(USERNAME_TEXT_COLOR);
        mChatView.setSendTimeTextColor(SEND_TIME_TEXT_COLOR);
        mChatView.setDateSeparatorColor(DATA_SEPARATOR_COLOR);
        mChatView.setMessageStatusTextColor(MESSAGE_STATUS_TEXT_COLOR);
        mChatView.setInputTextHint(INPUT_TEXT_HINT);
        mChatView.setMessageMarginTop(MESSAGE_MARGIN);
        mChatView.setMessageMarginBottom(MESSAGE_MARGIN);
        mChatView.setMaxInputLine(5);
        mChatView.setUsernameFontSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_small));
        mChatView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
        mChatView.setInputTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red500));
        mChatView.setInputTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);


        mChatView.setOnBubbleClickListener(new Message.OnBubbleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Message message) {
                mChatView.updateMessageStatus(message, MyMessageStatusFormatter.STATUS_SEEN);
                Toast.makeText(
                        MessengerActivity.this,
                        "click : " + message.getUser().getName() + " - " + message.getText(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });

        mChatView.setOnIconClickListener(new Message.OnIconClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIconClick(Message message) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        MessengerActivity.this,
                        "click : icon " + message.getUser().getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });

        mChatView.setOnIconLongClickListener(new Message.OnIconLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIconLongClick(Message message) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        MessengerActivity.this,
                        "Removed this message \n" + message.getText(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                mChatView.getMessageView().remove(message);
            }
        });

        //Click Send Button
        mChatView.setOnClickSendButtonListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                initUsers();
                //new message
                Message message = new Message.Builder()
                        .setUser(mUsers.get(0))
                        .setRight(true)
                        .setText(mChatView.getInputText())
                        .hideIcon(true)
                        .setStatusIconFormatter(new MyMessageStatusFormatter(MessengerActivity.this))
                        .setStatusTextFormatter(new MyMessageStatusFormatter(MessengerActivity.this))
                        .setStatusStyle(Message.Companion.getSTATUS_ICON())
                        .setStatus(MyMessageStatusFormatter.STATUS_DELIVERED)
                        .build();

                //Set to chat view
                mChatView.send(message);
                //Add message list
                mMessageList.add(message);
                //Reset edit text
                mChatView.setInputText("");

                receiveMessage(message.getText());
            }

        });

        //Click option button
        mChatView.setOnClickOptionButtonListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent intent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        }
        intent.setType("image/*");

        startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void receiveMessage(String sendText) {
        //Ignore hey
        if (!sendText.contains("hey")) {

            //Receive message
            final Message receivedMessage = new Message.Builder()
                    .setUser(mUsers.get(1))
                    .setRight(false)
                    .setText(ChatBot.INSTANCE.talk(mUsers.get(0).getName(), sendText))
                    .setStatusIconFormatter(new MyMessageStatusFormatter(MessengerActivity.this))
                    .setStatusTextFormatter(new MyMessageStatusFormatter(MessengerActivity.this))
                    .setStatusStyle(Message.Companion.getSTATUS_ICON())
                    .setStatus(MyMessageStatusFormatter.STATUS_DELIVERED)
                    .build();

            if (sendText.equals( Message.Type.PICTURE.name())) {
                receivedMessage.setText("Nice!");
            }

            // This is a demo bot
            // Return within 3 seconds
            if (mReplyDelay < 0) {
                mReplyDelay = (new Random().nextInt(4) + 1) * 1000;
            }
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mChatView.receive(receivedMessage);
                    //Add message list
                    mMessageList.add(receivedMessage);
                }
            }, mReplyDelay);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode != READ_REQUEST_CODE || resultCode != RESULT_OK || data == null) {
            return;
        }
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap picture = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            Message message = new Message.Builder()
                    .setRight(true)
                    .setText(Message.Type.PICTURE.name())
                    .setUser(mUsers.get(0))
                    .hideIcon(true)
                    .setPicture(picture)
                    .setType(Message.Type.PICTURE)
                    .setStatusIconFormatter(new MyMessageStatusFormatter(MessengerActivity.this))
                    .setStatusStyle(Message.Companion.getSTATUS_ICON())
                    .setStatus(MyMessageStatusFormatter.STATUS_DELIVERED)
                    .build();
            mChatView.send(message);
            //Add message list
            mMessageList.add(message);
            receiveMessage(Message.Type.PICTURE.name());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private void initUsers() {
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        //User id
        int myId = 0;
        //User icon
        Bitmap myIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.face_2);
        //User name
        String myName = "Michael";

        int yourId = 1;
        Bitmap yourIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.face_1);
        String yourName = "Emily";

        final User me = new User(myId, myName, myIcon);
        final User you = new User(yourId, yourName, yourIcon);

        mUsers.add(me);
        mUsers.add(you);
    }

    /**
     * Load saved messages
     * @param realm
     */
    private void loadMessages(Realm realm) {
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        mMessageList = AppData.getMessageList(this);
        if (mMessageList == null) {
            mMessageList = new MessageList();
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < mMessageList.size(); i++) {
                Message message = mMessageList.get(i);
                //Set extra info because they were removed before save messages.
                for (IChatUser user : mUsers) {
                    if (message.getUser().getId().equals(user.getId())) {
                        message.getUser().setIcon(user.getIcon());
                    }
                }
                if (!message.isDateCell() && message.isRight()) {
                    message.hideIcon(true);

                }
                message.setStatusStyle(Message.Companion.getSTATUS_ICON_RIGHT_ONLY());
                message.setStatusIconFormatter(new MyMessageStatusFormatter(this));
                message.setStatus(MyMessageStatusFormatter.STATUS_DELIVERED);
                messages.add(message);
            }
        }
        MessageView messageView = mChatView.getMessageView();
        messageView.init(messages);
        messageView.setSelection(messageView.getCount() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initUsers();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Save message
        mMessageList = new MessageList();
        mMessageList.setMessages(mChatView.getMessageView().getMessageList());
        AppData.putMessageList(this, mMessageList);
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        return mUsers;
    }


    public void setReplyDelay(int replyDelay) {
        mReplyDelay = replyDelay;
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        final String[] items = {
                getString(R.string.send_picture),
                getString(R.string.clear_messages)
        };

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.options))
                .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position) {
                        switch (position) {
                            case 0 :
                                openGallery();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                mChatView.getMessageView().removeAll();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What part are you stuck on?

Comment: @f1sh I want to save previous chat history and messages of user to database so that when user start chat they can see previous chat history and messages

Comment: I understand. But in which part of the code are you trying to do that? Where is your attempt?

Comment: I have create database and model and dao I already showed in the code

Comment: check MessengerActivity.java class

Comment: @f1sh do you understand

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new room database to store your messages. It's table should look like this:

| id | message | sendingUser | receivingUser |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Hello how are you? | John | David |
| 1 | Thanks, im good. | David | John |
| 2 | good to hear that! | John | David |

First create a new Message class. This class should look like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "message_table")
data class Message(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name= "message")
    var message: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sendingUser")
    var sendingUser: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "receivingUser")
    var receivingUser: String
)
```

Then create your MessageDatabase, like this:

```
@Database(entities = [Message::class], version = 1)
abstract class MessageDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun messageDao(): MessageDao
}
```

Next create your MessageDao

```
@Dao
interface MessageDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(message: Message)

    @Query("SELECT ALL * FROM message_table WHERE sendingUser= :sendingUser")
    suspend fun getMessageListFromSender(sendingUser: String): MutableList<Message>

    @Query("SELECT ALL * FROM message_table")
    suspend fun getMessageList(): MutableList<Message>

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(message: Message)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(message: Message)
}
```

At last you can initialize your room database like this:

```
private val roomDb = Room.databaseBuilder(
        getApplication(),
        MessageDatabase::class.java, "message_database"
    ).build()

private val messageDao = roomDb.messageDao()
```

Use messageDao, to make operations with the database, this example shows you how to get message list from a certain sender:

```
suspend fun getMessageListFromSender(sendingUser: String): MutableList<Message> {
     var list : MutableList<Message>
     with (messageDao) {
        list = this.getMessageListFromSender(sendingUser)
     }
     return list
}

viewModelScope.launch {
    getMessageListFromSender("John")
}
```